# Cisco 2851 Router DNS configuration questions

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, dns, cisco-commands

I'm using a Cisco 2851 Router and configuring through the Cisco Command-Line Interface and I'm trying to block certain https websites. Since I have heard that this router only has support for blocking http websites, I would like to have the websites such as twitter.com resolve to our company website.

My router is using a IP: 10.169.145.1 and the DNS Server that all of the computers are using by default is 65.32.1.xx

My question is: **How can I configure the computers on the network to use the DNS that I am setting up via the Cisco CLI when telnetting into 10.169.145.1?**

I tried putting the ip host redirect in and then changing the DNS address for a few computers, then trying to connect and ping the new name but it isn't working and I think I may be configuring the wrong DNS.

Comment: *Allocations for this OrgID serve Road Runner residential customers out of the Austin, TX and Tampa Bay, FL RDCs.* Home networking questions are off-topic. (plus, DNS blocking is 99% completely useless. It's trivial to change a host's dns settings.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configuration of your clients is off-topic. Clients get DNS server addresses from DHCP, or it is manually configured in each client. If your router is the DHCP server, you can change it to give a different DNS server. Other than that, you really can't change the client DNS server from your router.

Comment: My router is my DHCP server. So, say I made a windows server 2012 server run as DNS Server, then give my router that DNS Server, the new DNS entries I put into the windows server 2012 server would directly apply to the clients?

Comment: See this how to: http://www.firewall.cx/cisco-technical-knowledgebase/cisco-routers/257-cisco-router-dns-server.html. for using your router as the DNS server. If the router is the DHCP server, and you want to have the clients point to a different DNS server, then you put that into your router DHCP configuration. See this how to for that: http://www.firewall.cx/cisco-technical-knowledgebase/cisco-routers/812-cisco-router-dhcp-config.html

Comment: Currently, the DHCP pools are pointed to 65.32.1.xx (the public DNS server from our ISP), I could point those DHCP pools to the ip of the router instead, configure the router to use the 65.32.1.xx dns server (via "ip name-server 65.32.1.xx"), then add ip host name record in the router CLI, correct?

Comment: That is one way to do it, or you could set up your own DNS server and point to it.

Comment: What Ron said x1000. The Cisco IOS DNS server is one of the stupidest subsystems in the universe. (it's like satellite internet... absolute last resort.)